# is time integral of gaussian process a gaussian process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

If we have a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $X_t$ and $Y_t=\int_0^t X_s ds $, is $Y_t$ also a Gaussian process? is that true for any Gaussian process $X_t$? I know $Y_t$ is a Gaussian random variable for every $t$, but I want to know how to show the finite joint distribution is multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: How did you prove that $Y_t$ is Gaussian? One way to prove this is to write $Y_t$ as the pointwise limit of Riemann sums (which are Gaussian). It is not difficult to generalize this approach in order to show that the finite dimensional distributions are Gaussian.

Comment: You could use the fact that a collection of random variables is jointly Gaussian iff every linear combination of them is Gaussian.